# MySQL connection timeout error retrieving big results

Tags: mysql, windows

All of the sudden our MySQL 5.6 server (on Windows server) started to give us this error: "**Lost connection to server during query**".

We never had this problem before and we haven't touch MySQL config file for months.

This only happens with queries that return a lot of data.

Let's say table "NSA_email_log" has 250 000 rows and 8 longtext columns. 
Query like this:

```
Select * from NSA_email_log
```

will time out (and it will time out after like ~5 seconds of running),

but query like:

```
Select * from NSA_email_log group by email_address
```

(given that it will return less results but will run longer) will not.

Heck, right know I'm running this crazy query

```
 Select count(*) from NSA_email_log 
        join NSA_email_log
        join NSA_email_log
```

and no time out after 5 minutes of running.

Again, never had such problem (even running long queries returning a lot of data) and never changed any of the config options (regarding read timeout, connection timeout, packet size and so on).

Any way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is there any firewall between database and client? What's the connection idle timeout configuration?